# React-Native metro not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm new to react native and i've been following https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup and in the 'Start Metro' step, `npx react-native start` doesn't work
pls help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you installed Node first with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
```

Try `yarn start` or `npm start` after you installed node.

Comment: i did but it still shows the same error ```error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1331:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1379:12).....```

Comment: Metro will try to run on 8081. Make sure it's free or try to restart your computer if you keep the message.

You can also try to run it on a different port:
`yarn start --port 9988`